# How pass parameter in action of handlebars input component? Using Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I need to use this input component:

```
{{input type="textarea" value=fileName class="field" action="setFileName" on="key-press"}}
```

But I have to pass a parameter.

I don't want to do:

```
<input type="textarea" {{bind-attr value=fileName}} class="field" {{action 'setFileName' param on="keyPress"}}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible without extending the built-in `input` helper or writing your own. Can you elaborate on _why_ you need to pass a parameter? We might be able to help you find a better way to go about what you're doing.

Comment: If you aware of this `param` when you initialise the input, my guess, you can obtain it directly in the handler

Comment: Thanks by response. Can I extend the built-in input helper? @GJK,  I think that It is a component...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you could extend the built-in component to do what you want:

```
export default Ember.TextField.extend({
    sendAction: function(name) {
        if (name === 'action') {
            return this._super('action', this.get('value'), this.get('otherArgument'));
        } else {
            return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
});
```

You could then use it like this:

```
{{custom-input otherArgument=someValue action='callback'}}
```

Then, do this to capture the action:

```
actions: {
    callback: function(value, otherArgument) {
        // value is the text in the input
        // otherArgument is the `someValue` that you passed in
    }
}
```